# Cordova: Unable to call the JavaScript function instantly from for loop

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I’m calling the JavaScript function from Java class by using

**Java class code** (Which is extended from `CordovaPlugin`)

```
cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override @JavascriptInterface
     public void run() {
         webView.loadUrl("javascript:clickButton('" + id + "')");
     }
});
```

**JS file code**

```
window.clickButton = function(id){
      alert("clickButton " + id);
}
```

I’ve called this function in for loop, but for loop not calling this function instantly. It’s calling after finishing the whole for loop. Any one have the idea about this?...

Comment: post some more code... to show the for loop usage

Comment: and it is never a good to perform such actions inside for each iterator

Comment: Hi Rahul Khurana, I'm just parsing the JSON. In that parsing i've used for loop. In that loop i'm calling the function.

Can plz suggest me the good process, instead of calling the function in each iterator

Comment: Without the alert method did you tried putting console.log?

Comment: Now only i've tried with console.log but no use. During this time again i've debugged but as i said in question `webView.loadUrl("javascript:clickButton('" + id + "')");` not executing with for loop. After completing the for loop only it's executing...

Comment: are you trying to achieve this functionality after pageLoadFinished?

Comment: No i'm not trying for that

Comment: ok. then do your changes inside onPageFinished method.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll try as you suggested...